# TrimDuplicates element of Microsoft.Search.Query Webservice causes a FormatException

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to search through a site collection and find all sites that contain a particular file. TrimDuplicates is supposed to be the right way to do that. I'm calling QueryEx of the WebService object with the following XML as the string argument.

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>
  <Query>
    <TrimDuplicates includeid="false">False</TrimDuplicates>
    <SupportedFormats>
      <Format revision='1'>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document:Document</Format>
    </SupportedFormats>
    <Context>
      <QueryText language='en-us' type='STRING'>
        "filenameForQuery"
      </QueryText>
    </Context>
  </Query>
</QueryPacket>
```

The response from search.asmx is a 500 error with System.FormatException as the only piece of useful information.

It's only the TrimDuplicates element that is triggering the formatexception. Fiddling the case of the two Falses hasn't had any effect so far.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually blindingly obvious - remove the includeid attribute and make the content of TrimDuplicates lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to point out that includeid should actually be an integer value.

[More here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd955992%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

But as you said, it's not necessary.

Comment: Wellcome to SO. As this is your first post. please note this seems more a comment than an answer. Take a look to this topic: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I would have commented if my rep was over 50, but thanks for the suggestion.